# Input text causing unnecessary button rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

I need to **check the fields** and i **need to pass several properties** to the button. **String, Object, Array, Func** and i **need** **usestate be an object like example**. Any solution to not cause re-rendering?

EDIT: **I need to do a way that when the user fills in the input the button does not re-render.**

EDIT 2: when I use the primitive type useState(string). And I make the comparison works , useState of type Object making comparison causes re-rendering on button:

**code below does not cause re-rendering**

```
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");


  const validateFields = useCallback(() => {
    if (email === "") {
      alert("Empty e-mail.");

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }, [email]);
```

**code below does CAUSE re-rendering - (comparison with object)**

```
 const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const validateFields = useCallback(() => {
    if (userData.email === "") {
      alert("Empty e-mail.");

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }, [userData]);
```

project link : https://codesandbox.io/s/tender-allen-tfklv8?file=/src/components/Button.js

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import Button from "./components/Button";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: ""
  });

  const validateFields = useCallback(() => {
    if (userData.email.trim() === "") {
      alert("Empty e-mail.");

      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }, [userData]);

  const handleAPI = useCallback(() => {
    if (validateFields()) {
      console.log("handleAPI");
    }
  }, [validateFields]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={userData.email}
        onChange={(event) =>
          setUserData((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            email: event.target.value
          }))
        }
      />
      <Button onClick={handleAPI} />
    </div>
  );
}



const Button = ({ onClick }) => {
  console.log("------------Button render---------------");

  return <button onClick={onClick}>BUTTON DEFAULT</button>;
};

export default memo(Button);
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear. React re-renders everything, unlike Vue, for example. Please revise to explain the _problem_ that this re-rendering causes.

Comment: Don't tell us down here. _Revise your post._ That doesn't answer my question anyway. It just restates the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're intending to use the `validateData` function when clicking on the button, there's no need for the `handleAPI` function to be within a `useCallback` hook that depends on `validateData`. Whenever you click on the button, the `validateData` function will be called and will validate the desired data with whatever value is currently in the `userData` state variable.

Comment: I put this useCallback to try to make the button not render when filling the input. I need to make a way for the button not to render when the user fills in the input.

Comment: You wish to not make it re-render or to not render *at all*?